# particle engine in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Does anyone know the tutorial of a particle engine in cocos2d?

Answer (score 2):

**In your ".h" file:**

```
 CCParticleSun *sun;
```

**In your ".m" file:**

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) 
    {
    sun = [[CCParticleSun alloc] initWithTotalParticles:180];
    sun.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"yourparticle.png"];
    sun.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
    sun.speed = 30.0f;
    sun.duration = 0.5f;
    sun.position = ccp(240, 160);
    sun.startSize = 5;
    sun.endSize = 50;
    sun.life = 0.6;
    [self addChild:sun];
    }
}
```

This will create a nice little explosion effect.  You have to use a particle image: 
[**Particle I Created**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21177870/exp-hd.png)

`Here is the image:`

[Particle http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21177870/exp-hd.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21177870/exp-hd.png)

There are many different types of particles: 
[**Particles Documentation That You Should Have Read Before Asking On This Website!**](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:particles)

### **Seriously though, you should use Google and the documentation.  Don't be lazy.**

Comment: I seem to have deleted the image, if anyone needs it just ask :)